# Convert jquery object to DOM and use appendChild function

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have to move input element. In variable test I'm getting good element:

```
var test = $('#AttributeValue_StringRepresentation').parent('td');
```

But I don't have any idea how to use appendChild with it, I tried:

```
test.appenChild(document.getElementById(AttributeValueId));
test[0].appenChild(document.getElementById(AttributeValueId));
```

I've tried also

```
document.getElementsByName(test)[0].appenChild(document.getElementById(AttributeValueId));
```

Generally my ideas finished, I found few solutions but it's now working. I don't have an ID of test variable or anything and I'm stuck

Comment: `test[0].appenChild(document.getElementById(AttributeValueId));` should work, However you use `.append()` i.e. `test.append(document.getElementById(AttributeValueId))`

Comment: `appenChild !== appendChild`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in your code... Not

```
appenChild
```

but...

```
appendChild
```